# GaussianMixture sklearn starting priors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

I have a mixture model :

```
gm = mixture.GaussianMixture(
                n_components=3,
                covariance_type="tied",
                weights_init=[w1,w2,w3],
                means_init=[m1,m2,m3],
                random_state=0).fit(datas)
```

But, the result of the clusterization is not perfect, so I calculated from my initials datas 3 priors to ameliorate the clustering. I would like to use these priors as initial starting points in the EM algorithm of the gaussian mixture model.

Initial means : are they starting points ? Can I replace them by my new priors or is it something else ?

I saw :

```
sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture
```

But, it seems really different, like I can't initialize my weigths, just priors weigths and I don't know if it's the same thing (I'm not an expert in statistics...), and there are too many options that I don't understand...

How can I use my new priors as starting points of the EM algorithm in my Gaussian Mixture ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A statistician helped me to answer my question and it is `initial_means` that are the starting points used for the EM algorithm. 
I just have to give my new priors in the `initial_means` in `GaussianMixture` function, no need to use `BayesianGaussianMixture`.

Comment: Which approach did you use to set ```initial_means```? I was thinking about combining ```KernelDensity``` from sklearn to smooth the points out, and then use ```find_peaks``` from scipy and use the latter as ```initial_means```. What was your solution? I'd appreciate ifyou could share it with us. Thanks.